# Passing non-NULL argv to MPI_Comm_spawn

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

Suppose that my program (let's call it `prog_A`) starts as a single MPI process.
And later I want program `prog_A` to spawn `n` MPI processes (let's call them `prog_B`) using `MPI_Comm_spawn` with the same arguments I passed to `prog_A`.

For example, if I run `prog_A` with the arguments `200 100 10`

```
mpiexec -n 1 prog_A 200 100 10
```

I want `prog_B` to be provided with the same argments `200 100 10`.

How can I do this? I tried the following but it does not work.

```
  char ** newargv = new char*[3];//create new argv for childs

  newargv[0] = new char[50];
  newargv[1] = new char[50];
  newargv[2] = new char[50];

  strcpy(newargv[0],argv[1]);//copy argv to newargv
  strcpy(newargv[1],argv[2]);
  strcpy(newargv[2],argv[3]);

  MPI_Comm theother; 

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
  MPI_Comm_spawn("prog_B",newargv,numchildprocs,  
             MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &theother,  
             MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE); 

  MPI_Finalize();
```

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Is there an error message? Does it crash? Does it hang?

Comment: Is `prog_B` in the same directory?

Comment: @WesleyBland Prog_A crashes upon calling MPI_Comm_spawn.
yes...they are in the same directory.

Comment: Does it dump a core? Give any sort of error message? Can you post a full, compiling example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't `NULL` terminate your argv list. Here's the important part of the [MPI standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.0/mpi-20-html/node95.htm#Node95) (emphasis added):

> The argv argument argv is an array of strings containing arguments
>   that are passed to the program. The first element of argv is the first
>   argument passed to command, not, as is conventional in some contexts,
>   the command itself. ***The argument list is terminated by NULL in C and
>   C++ and an empty string in Fortran.*** In Fortran, leading and trailing
>   spaces are always stripped, so that a string consisting of all spaces
>   is considered an empty string. The constant MPI_ARGV_NULL may be used
>   in C, C++ and Fortran to indicate an empty argument list. In C and
>   C++, this constant is the same as NULL.

You just need to add a NULL to the end of your list. Here's the corrected code (translated to C since I didn't have the C++ bindings installed on my laptop):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char ** newargv = malloc(sizeof(char *)*4);//create new argv for childs
    int numchildprocs = 1;
    MPI_Comm theother;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_get_parent(&theother);

    if (MPI_COMM_NULL != theother) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SPAWNED!\n");
    } else {
        newargv[0] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
        newargv[1] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
        newargv[2] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
        newargv[3] = NULL;

        strncpy(newargv[0],argv[1], 50);//copy argv to newargv
        strncpy(newargv[1],argv[2], 50);
        strncpy(newargv[2],argv[3], 50);

        fprintf(stderr, "SPAWNING!\n");
        MPI_Comm_spawn("./prog_B",newargv,numchildprocs,
                MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &theother,
                MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);
    }

    MPI_Comm_free(&theother);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to copy the argument vector at all. All you have to do is make use of the provisions of the C99 standard, which requires that `argv` should be NULL-terminated:

```
MPI_Comm theother;

// Passing &argc and &argv here is a thing of the past (MPI-1)
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

MPI_Comm_spawn("prog_B", argv+1, numchildprocs,
         MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &theother,
         MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);

MPI_Finalize();
```

Note the use of `argv+1` in order to skip over the first argument (the program name). The benefit of that code is that it works with any number of arguments passed to the original program.